# MatLab figure date and time static text

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

**checkbox1's** callback for date and time:

```
m=1;
while m==1
m=get(hObject,'value');
txt=datestr(now);
set(handles.datetime,'string',txt);
pause(1);
end
```

can you please help me to **remove the checkbox** that if I will push the RUN button the **datetime static text** will automatically call the date and time.

**EDIT REPLY:**

[image]

I used your code and this is how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this [post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53858).

Do a toogle button that have 2 status : Run/Stop. So you will push your button and do

```
if (get(hObject,'value'))
   set(handles.toogleRun,'string','stop');
else
   set(handles.toogleRun,'string','Run');
end

while (get(hObject,'value'))
   txt=datestr(now);
   set(handles.datetime,'string',txt);
   drawnow;
end
```

This is the callback for the toogleRun button.

**EDIT :** So for using the timer instead use that code :

```
function my_callback_fcn(obj, event)

txt = datestr(now)
set(handles.datetime,'string',txt);
```

And into your Opening GUI function create a timer and set is callback function to the function you already create.

```
t = timer('StartDelay', 1, 'Period', 0.1);
t.TimerFcn = {@my_callback_fcn};
```

So just add `start(t)` on a button or whatever

Comment: @Alexander Bizeau Isn't that just the same as the checkbox calling the time whenever I will push the togglebutton? what I want to do is whenever the figure file appears, the date and time will automatically appear too in the static text getting rid of buttons, toggles, and checkbox.

Comment: Okay, Because you said in your question If I will push the run button, i tought you need it with a button, but have a look to timer then. I'll post code soon : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerclass.html;jsessionid=86c24ada79ddcdf5b1f8cf1c56ed

Comment: So I edit my post. The timer will start 1 seconds after you press the button and will call is function on every period so 0.1 second.

Comment: How can I define the TimerFcn? this will be my first time using a timer

Comment: You're using GUI or script only? If you use GUI, just add the `function my_callback_fcn` in my edit any where in your code. Else, create a new script function and copy the callback, so you'll be able to call it from another script.

Comment: I used your code and why is the TimerFcn not turning into blue. it's like it doesn't have a function in it and I put the timer code in a pushbutton and I just pasted the callback function you created on top of it. check my **EDIT** at the top to see the TimerFcn

Comment: Yes, It well done, just add `start(t)` after `t.TimerFcn = {...}`. (My comment below my post.)

Comment: And Maybe I miss a `drawnow;` into my_callback_fcn to redraw the text box and maybe add an `guidata(hObject, handles);`

Comment: I'm still getting error like **Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-6' 

Not enough input arguments.**

Comment: I dont' know try to use try/catch to see the error. That strange, I don't have any more informations sorry.